# request.getHeader("User-Agent") throws npe

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to confirm whether request.getHeader("User-Agent") can throw null pointer exception, if yes then in what are the cases when it throws NPE.

```
<% if (request.getHeader("User-Agent").toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") != -1) { %>
```

Thanks  in Advance

Answer (score 13):

No,

```
request.getHeader("User-Agent")
```

should never throw a `NPE`, it might however return `null` in which case your code would through a `NPE`.

(I'm assuming request is an instance of `HTTPServletRequest` or similar)

Comment: This is my mistake I am getting null ponter exception since request.getHeader("User_Agent") is null. i.e.Property with user-agent is missing in request header.

Comment: Yes. So the answer to your question was "No" - the answer to your intended question is "yes" (it can return null) I assume.

Comment: What if the request is null? :)

Answer (score 6):

`request.getHeader("User-Agent")` might return `null` if `User-Agent` header was not sent by the client (and it is not mandatory). Change your code to:

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
if (userAgent != null && userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") != -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there is possibilities to dont send any kind of "User-Agent" header. In that case your code throw NPE - `request.getHeader("User-Agent")` == null => null has no `toLowerCase()` method.

Change your if to following:
`<% if (request.getHeader("User-Agent") != null && request.getHeader("User-Agent").toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") != -1) { %>`

Browser decide how to introduce yourself to server, there is gazillion browser addons which allow to change useragent to whatever text you want. Another example, your internet gateway surely could change/remove `user-agent` from any http packet which comes through its.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
Can you please suggest the scenarios where we get Header user agent property as null ?

Comment: Browser decide how to introduce yourself to server, there is gazylion browser addons which allow to change useragent to whatever text you want. Another example, your internet gateway surely could change/remove user-agent from any http packet which comes through its.

Comment: In a JSP you shouldn't do a null check, but write: `if !empty request.getHeader("User-Agent")`

Answer (score 0):

Most of the browsers or clients send `User-Agent header` in which case, the `request.getHeader("User-Agent")` should not be null.

But, some clients/browsers might not send `User-Agent header` in which case your code can throw NPE.

You should handle the null case.